# Why is self.kill() not removing the object from the group?

Tags: python, pygame

I've asked this question a while ago but the answers weren't entirely helpful and I don't believe I posted a minimum reproducible example. I'm trying to kill my bullet after some time (self.lifetime) has passed. The self.kill() command is executed, but it does not remove the bullet from the camera group, which is what I use to draw all bullets.

The relevant code:
Player.shoot():

```
    def shoot(self, pos):
    self.current_time = pg.time.get_ticks()
    # Allow the player to shoot (but not continuously)
    if not self.shooting and self.current_time - self.last_shot_time >= self.shoot_cooldown:
        self.last_shot_time = self.current_time
        # Setting self.shooting to True so that only one bullet is created
        self.shooting = True
        # Creating the bullet
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery, "bullet", pos, 2, a_s.camera)

    # Reset self.shooting
    self.shooting = False
```

Bullet.update():

```
    def update(self):
    # Killing the bullet after self.lifetime has passed
    if pg.time.get_ticks() - self.start_time > self.lifetime:
        self.kill()
        print("Killing")
    # Moving the bullet (accurately, self.x is float while self.rect.x can only be int)
    self.x += self.vel_x
    self.y += self.vel_y
    self.rect.x = int(self.x)
    self.rect.y = int(self.y)
```

Entity class: (bullet inherits from this)

```
class Entity(pg.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self, speed, group):
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.speed = speed
    group.add(self)
```

I'm also adding a pastebin to allow you to reproduce this example, however you will need 3 images titled "ground.png", "player.png", and "bullet.png" in the directory to run it.

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/Vi57HF1i

Images I use (credit to someone else, not sure where I got them from): https://i.stack.imgur.com/09ocm.jpg

Comment: @Rabbid76
There is, because the bullet is not being properly killed. I don't know why it's not being removed from camera group. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The bullet is not getting removed from the group in the first place, which is strange. 1 - They are in the camera_group, but get removed after self.kill() and should no longer be referenced. 2 - This seems possible, I'll look into it. 3 - I don't think this is the case. Many more - There are a lot of places this could be coming from, this bug has plagued the code for too long! Thanks for your help, I'll post an edit if I discover the problem.

Comment: I know you're right, which is why this bug is annoying as hell. I've run self.alive() and self.groups() before and after the self.kill() method, and both times it shows that the self does not belong to any groups? Despite the bullet class calling Entity.__init__, which calls the group.add(self) on the bullet. Perhaps it's coming from there? No clue man. But the bullet is seemingly both a part of the camera group and not, schrodinger's bullet :/

Comment: Thank you, that's actually super useful to know. I'll try and find where it may be coming from, already found an unnecessary pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__ which I never previously saw, going to keep looking and hopefully fix it.

Comment: Oh my goddd, you're absolutely right. I was inheriting pg.sprite.Sprite twice which messed things up. I've just changed some of it around so that whenever we inherit from Entity, we don't have to inherit from Element also, (element is required for screen resolution changing), and I've added Element.__init__ to Entity class itself. The bug is completely fixed. I cannot express how grateful I am!

By the way, other than this particular mishap, is there any other negatives about the way I'm inheriting? The way I see it, Element's logic is required for all elements, might as well inherit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with the [Multiple Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance). Each * `Bullet` has 2 base classes which are derived from `pygame.sprite.Sprite` So each `Bullet` actually consists of 2 sprites. This is not intentional and cause kill not to work. When you call `kill`, just the "first" `pygame.sprite.Sprite` object is removed from the *Groups*.
The problem can be reproduced with the following minimal example:

```py
import pygame

elementGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()
entityGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()

class Element(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        elementGroup.add(self)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        entityGroup.add(self)

class Bullet(Element, Entity):
    def __init__(self):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        Element.__init__(self)

bullet = Bullet()

print(len(elementGroup), len(entityGroup))
bullet.kill()
print(len(elementGroup), len(entityGroup))
```

Output:

> ```
> 1 1
> 0 1
> ```

To solve the problem, you need to restructure your code. Each class should be derived from `pygame.sprite.Sprite` only once.